# Upload an image automatically to s3

Tags: javascript, facebook, angularjs, amazon-s3

I have an upload form that is currently working where the user choose his/her desired avatar/picture. But now I'm integrating facebook api and upon successful registration using FB Javascript SDK, I will then have to upload the user facebook profile pic into our S3.

```
<img src="https://fullpath/mypic.png" id="image"/>
```

I've researched around on converting the image to blob or something.
So how do I automatically upload mypic.png to my s3? Please any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you'll need to do this on the server side; as a browser won't be able to access items on different domains via JavaScript.  The reason for this is to prevent cross site scripting attacks.

Comment: @Reboog711 you do not need to do this server side, see my answer below. Please vote or approve if this answer helped you original poster.

Answer (score 1):

Use the AWS JS SDK.

Here is the getting started guide: http://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/browser/

It's actually quite simple once you get the roles setup.

No server side code needed!

Of course you will need to get the image data first like this:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 512;
canvas.height = 512;
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 512, 512);
var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/webp', 0.5); //webp and 50% compression

var params = {
  Key:Date.now().toString(), //example
  ContentType:'text/plain', //sending a base64 text string
  Body:data //the base64 string is now the body
};

bucket.putObject(params, function(err, data) { ... });
```

Comment: Note that this approach will not work in IE9 and older.

Comment: Noted, I feel this answers the original question though, despite the limitations of the AWS JS SDK, and the answer below was false. Would be easy to implement in OP's Java backend as well, but here you have it happening on the client side for free.

Comment: So, I should give the JS client the credentials needed to write to my S3 bucket? Or do should we provide it with a signed URL for writing (if that is possible) - and that needs to come from the serverside.

Comment: If you want the images uploaded on behalf of your application then you will need a server side solution, but this would be a super tiny proxy style method written in Node.js. For the client to upload on their behalf they would need to authenticate through FB, Google, or Amazon first and then you can do the upload strictly client side.

Answer (score -1):

you can't do that from the browser, you need a server side script which will receive your upload and send it to s3. which framework do you use on the server side?

Comment: we're using java as our backend.

Comment: You DO NOT need a server side script, see AWS JS SDK Javascript in the browser: http://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/browser/